# Data exchange between console application and GUI

Tags: c++, user-interface

I am planning to write a Library Information System in C++.

I need to create the business logic in C++. I will create the application as an engine which gets the input process the data dumps the output. I have to give the flexibility to for the user to create GUI in any programming language say C++, Python, Java or as a Webform inn PHP,JSP or ASP. In short words the console application is separate and GUI application is separate. The GUI application has to read the data from user send to console application. The console application will process it and send the data to GUI application for display.

Which is the best way to transfer the data between console application and GUI?
One option in my mind is GUI will read the data from form and save it to a JSON file and invoke console application and pass JSON fle to it. The console application will process it and save the output as another JSON file, the GUI program will parse it and display it.

Is there any other better option? Should I use any data transfer protocol to transfer data? If so which one should I use?

Comment: This sounds very much like polling opinion, which is off-topic on SO. There may be some Stack Exchange site where the question is on-topic.

Comment: I dont know writing data to JSON file is a good practice. I just wanted to get an expert advice.

Comment: Just make sure every concurrent instance of the console program has its own files.